# Calculate Time Between Logins by User in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate the time difference between 2 login events in BigQuery, by user. I want to understand how long it takes between logins for each user.

I've tried with the following query:

```
Select user_id, timestamp,
    timestamp_diff(timestamp, (lag(timestamp)over (partition by user_id order by timestamp), minute)) as 
    time_diff
from table 
order by user_id, timestamp
```

**Sample Data**

| user_id | event | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | Login | 2021-02-20 00:00:00 UTC |
| bbb | Login | 2021-02-20 00:02:00 UTC |
| aaa | Login | 2021-02-20 00:01:00 UTC |
| ccc | Login | 2021-02-20 00:02:00 UTC |
| aaa | Login | 2021-02-20 00:01:00 UTC |
| aaa | Login | 2021-02-20 00:50:00 UTC |
| bbb | Login | 2021-02-20 00:13:00 UTC |
| ccc | Login | 2021-02-20 00:46:00 UTC |

My result should be a column wth the time between the current and the previous login event, the first event would be `NULL`.

Comment: please include expect output and your current output.

Comment: And what is the issue with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra parentheses in your query.  So, written correctly:

```
Select user_id, timestamp,
       timestamp_diff(timestamp, 
                      lag(timestamp) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp),
                      minute
                     ) as time_diff
from table 
order by user_id, timestamp;
```

You might also want to add the filter `where event = 'Login'`.

Answer (score 0):

> the parenthesis seemed to actually be causing the issue

It is much easier to spot such type of the "errors" when query is less cluttered

Consider below example

```
Select user_id, timestamp,
    timestamp_diff(timestamp, lag(timestamp) over win, minute) as time_diff
from `project.dataset.table`
window win as (partition by user_id order by timestamp)
order by user_id, timestamp
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]